# Whats wrong with sp_rename with column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using following SQL command with `sp_rename` to rename a column.

```
USE MYSYS;
GO
EXEC sp_rename 'MYSYS.SYSDetails.AssetName', 'AssetTypeName', 'COLUMN';
GO
```

But it is causing an error:

> Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 238
>   Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.

Please suggest how to rename a column using `sp_rename`.

[ this command I am using found at [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) ]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
USE MYSYS;
GO
EXEC sp_rename 'SYSDetails.AssetName', 'AssetTypeName', 'COLUMN';
GO
```

sp_rename (Transact-SQL) ([msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql)):

> [ @objname = ] 'object_name'
>
> Is the current qualified or nonqualified name of the user object or
>   data type. **If the object to be renamed is a column in a table,
>   object_name must be in the form table.column or schema.table.column.**
>   If the object to be renamed is an index, object_name must be in the
>   form table.index or schema.table.index. If the object to be renamed is
>   a constraint, object_name must be in the form schema.constraint.
>
> Quotation marks are only necessary if a qualified object is specified.
>   **If a fully qualified name, including a database name, is provided, the
>   database name must be the name of the current database.** object_name is
>   nvarchar(776), with no default.

Syntax with a fully qualified name:

```
USE Database
GO
EXEC sp_rename 'Database.Schema.TableName.ColumnName', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN';
GO
```

If you want to have in the *objectname* a fully qualified name you should also specified **schema**. So if your *SYSDetails* table is in the *dbo* schema, this code should work for you:

```
USE MYSYS;
GO
EXEC sp_rename 'MYSYS.dbo.SYSDetails.AssetName', 'AssetTypeName', 'COLUMN';
GO
```

Comment: why it does not work with dbname.tblname.colname ? will you please let me know ?

Comment: @Aditya check my answer again :) In the msdn doc you can find answer :)

Comment: @kmatyaszek `MYSYS.dbo.SYSDetails.AssetName` isn't in the form table.column or schema.table.column. I know it works in other contexts, but the documentation you quote doesn't say it also works with `sp_rename`.

Answer (score 2):

Double-check that your table `SYSDetails` exists. If the target table doesn't exist you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because column name was not correct. Sometimes wrong table name or wrong column name may cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked

```
USE **DatabaseName**
GO
EXEC sp_rename 'Schema.TableName.ColumnName', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN';
GO
```

Here is the example which worked for me

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.Facility.facilityName', 'FacilityName', 'COLUMN'
```