# ASP.NET MVC. How fix "Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous ..." error. when a migration is added?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I added the fallowing Fluent API into my context.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){
    modelBuilder.Entity<MainClass>().HasOptional(a => a.simpleItems).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);       
}
```

`add-migration` resulted in the fallowing migration:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.SimpleItems", "MainClass_id", "dbo.MainClasses");
    DropIndex("dbo.SimpleItems", new[] { "MainClass_id" });
    RenameColumn(table: "dbo.MainClasses", name: "MainClass_id", newName: "simpleItems_id");
    CreateIndex("dbo.MainClasses", "simpleItems_id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.MainClasses", "simpleItems_id", "dbo.SimpleItems", "id", cascadeDelete: true);
    DropColumn("dbo.SimpleItems", "MainClass_id");
}
```

But I'm not able to perform the migration. when i type  `update-database -verbose` I got the fallowing error:

> Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.

How can i fix it?

P.S. Using verbose Im able to see that the error occurs when the update-database are executes creates this line:

```
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.MainClasses.MainClass_id', @newname = N'simpleItems_id', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
```

P.S. If I remove the all the migrations and enable a new migration from scratch, the database is successfully updated. The problem exists specifically with this migration above.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the database name? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20440366/2496266

Comment: Also there are a handful of suggestions to try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14848385/2496266).